Is Torsion Observable?
Are there, have there been, or could there be any experiments that might detect any torsion in our corner of the universe? Any results?
Or is torsion an unobservable?

Torsion of what?

Thanks for the comment/question. I've clarified with a wiki link. Torsion considered wrt GR.

I do not know if there was any follow up to this paper, but there was some thoughts on using Gravity Probe B...

Thanks for that reference! Apparently "It is well-entrenched folklore that torsion gravity theories predict observationally negligible torsion in the solar system, since torsion (if it exists) couples only to the intrinsic spin of elementary particles, not to rotational angular momentum."

@Ric I think the point you made in my answer is correct: torsion shouldn't affect geodesics. I'll think more about it, but in the meantime I deleted my answer

If you're considering the dynamics resulting from Einstein-Cartan theory, then torsion can only be measured inside a given concentration of matter if, of course, its spin density is non-zero. I gave some details about this in your other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/813660/277861. And, to add to what @NíckolasAlves said, when torsion is introduced there are two ways in which you can classify curves: auto-parallel curves, and geodesic curves. When there's no torsion, these two concepts coincide, but this isn't true in general.

I would add that with torsion, there's an ambiguity about which curves should particles follow: the geodesics or the auto-parallel curves?  The first option comes from the stationary action principle, while the second option comes from the inertia principle.  Many theorists prefer the second option, but how could we know?  And there's also a possibility that the torsion do propagates outside of matter, according to modifications to the Einstein-Cartan-Kibble-Sciama theory (for which torsion do not propagates).

I wonder about Torsion outside of spinny matter. In QM, can't particles of matter (like electrons) extend beyond what one might consider the boundaries of some object? Can't particles in theory have a non-zero (albeit small) probability of existing anywhere in the universe?

The presence of torsion should violate the equivalence principle, which hasn't been observed so far.
